# Blue Yeti mic with iPad Pro

Tags: audio, macbook-pro, microphone, ipad

I’m trying to use the Blue Yeti microphone on an iPad Pro like I would with a MacBook Pro. I’m wondering if the same kind of control features are available on the iPad Pro (or any iOS devices).

With the MacBook Pro, the Blue Yeti microphone input level can be controlled via system preferences. Also the MacBook Pro’s built in speakers can be used for audio output with automatic echo cancellation.

When plugged into an iPad Pro (using a USB C adaptor), I could not find a way to adjust the input level of the Blue Yeti. Also the only way I could (or know how to) get audio output is by plugging in headphones directly into the Yeti. I could not figure out how to use the built in speakers of the iPad.

Does anyone know how to make the Yeti work on an iPad Pro the same way as on a MacBook Pro? Thanks

Comment: It does and it works. I’m just trying maximize the controls

Comment: GarageBand allows adjusting the microphone level with Blue Yeti Nano. (I came here looking for an answer how to adjust the input level in the Camera app. The level is unusably low for me there.)

Comment: @hsivonen thanks for suggestion. Will try that. So happens last night i tried recording video with camera app and blue yeti and noticed a slight lag in the video. But did not notice the sound level being too low

Comment: I don't know how to change audio output, but you can adjust the input level using the dial on the microphone itself.